# Ignore parts of an equation with multiple variable in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I want to use the linear version of a somewhat big equation which is output by my Mathematica code. For simplicity I will use the following example equation here:

```
Test = 3 x + x y + 8 y
```

Now, I want to keep only the first order terms, so that for `x` that will be `3` and for `y` that will be `8`. I have tried to get those using

```
Coefficient[Test, x]
Coefficient[Test, y]
```

However these give me for x:

```
3+y
```

and for `y`:

```
8+x
```

Is there any way that I can use Mathematica to ignore the terms that depend in both `x` and `y` simultaneously? I have tried doing `y x = 0` before I use coefficient but that doesn't work either since it only implies that one of them has to be zero but not which one.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a scaling variable to do this:

```
Test = 3 x+x y+8 y
Normal @ Series[Test /. v:x|y->v t, {t, 0, 1}] /. t->1
```

> 3 x + 8 y + x y
>
> 3 x + 8 y

Comment: `Series` can be a pain in the neck sometimes. I prefer to use `PadeApproximant[..., {t, 0, {1, 0}}]` instead of `Normal @ Series[..., {t, 0, 1}]`.

Answer (score 4):

Looks more complicated than working with `Series`, but if you are going to work a lot with polynomials, then `CoefficientRules` and `FromCoefficientRules` might get useful anyways.

```
FromCoefficientRules[
 Cases[
  CoefficientRules[3 x + x y + 8 y, {x, y}],
  Rule[a_, b_] /; (Total[a] <= 1)
  ],
 {x, y}
 ]
```

> 3 x + 8 y

Comment: Thanks, But, this seem to work well for two arguments but I may have more than 3 even, any way this could be addapted?

Comment: Just give your new expression as first argument to `CoefficientRules` and the list of variables as second arguments to `CoefficientRules` and `FromCoefficientRules` (e.g., `{x,y,z,...}` instead of `{x,y}`). See also the documentation of `FromCoefficientRules`, `CoefficientRules`, and `Cases`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that `CoefficientRules` and `FromCoefficientRules` is a good choice here.

```
CoefficientRules[3 x + x y + 8 y, {x, y}]

(*{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 3, {0, 1} -> 8}*)
```

Keep only the first order terms

```
DeleteCases[%, HoldPattern[a_ -> _] /; Total[a] >= 2]

(*{{1, 0} -> 3, {0, 1} -> 8}*)
```

Finally construct the function in terms of $x$ and $y$

```
FromCoefficientRules[%, {x, y}]

(*3 x + 8 y*)
```

Changing the pattern inside `DeleteCases` you can modify the function the way you want.

Comment: Isn’t your answer very similar to [Henrik’s earlier one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174473/27951) above?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming polynomials are to be linearized at the origin, here are a few ways using [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html):

Homogeneous linear part:

```
CoefficientArrays[test][[2]].Variables[test2]
(*  3 x + 8 y  *)
```

Degree at most 1 part:

```
test2 = 3 x + x y + 8 y + 2;
ca = CoefficientArrays[test];
ca[[1]] + [[2]].Variables[test2]
(*  2 + 3 x + 8 y  *)
```

For arbitrary degree (2 variants):

```
deg = 1;
With[{vars = Variables[test2]},
 Total[
  Nest[Dot[#, vars] &, #, ArrayDepth[#]] & /@
   CoefficientArrays[test2][[;; deg + 1]]
  ]]
(*  2 + 3 x + 8 y  *)

Inner[
 Function[{a, v}, Nest[#.v &, a, ArrayDepth[a]]],
 CoefficientArrays[test2][[;; deg + 1]],
 {1, Variables[test2]},
 Plus
 ]
(*  2 + 3 x + 8 y  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

> ***to ignore the terms that depend on both x and y simultaneously***

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Replace[# ,  e_ /; And @@ (Internal`DependsOnQ[e, #] & /@ {##2}) :> 0,  ∞] &;

f[3 x + x y + 8 y, x, y]
```

> 3 x + 8 y

```
f[3 x + 5 2^x  y + 8 y, x, y]
```

> 3 x + 8 y

Answer (score 1):

a simple way.

```
Test = 3 x + x y + 8 y // Expand;

vars=Variables[Test];

prodterms=Apply[Times, Subsets[vars, {2,Length[vars]}], 2]

(*   {x y}   *)

Test /. Thread[prodterms -> 0]

(*   3 x + 8 y   *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[Test, FreeQ[#, x y] &]
```

> 3 x + 8 y

```
Select[Test, MemberQ[#, x ] &]
```

> 3 x + x y

Comment: This is just a reminder, that your question pops up in the "Low Quality" posts because it contains no description at all. I know that these two small expressions are self-explanatory and a description is hardly needed, but others might down-vote it because of this.