# Removing higher order terms

Tags: series-expansion, algebra

I have a very long expression in terms of the three functions u1, u2, u3. I am writing below only a small number of terms. I would like to define a ***rule*** that keeps terms of order three or less of any multiplication of u1, u2,u3 and their derivatives.

```
 ss=  u2[x, y, z, t]^3 + A*u2[x, y, z, t]^4 + Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][u1][x, y, z, t] + 
 (3*λ*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][u1][x, y, z, t]^2*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0]  [u1][x, y, z, t])/2 + 
  (5*CC*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][u1][x, y, z, t]^4*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][u1][x,y, z, t])/4 + μ*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][u2][x, y, z, t]
```

The output should be:

```
  u2[x, y, z, t]^3 + Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][u1][x, y, z, t] + (3*λ*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][u1][x, y, z, t]^2*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][u1][x, y, z, t])/2 + 
 μ*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][u2][x, y, z, t]
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore parts of an equation with multiple variable in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174471/ignore-parts-of-an-equation-with-multiple-variable-in-mathematica)

Comment: It does not seem a duplicate to me. None of the answers to that question would give the correct answer to the example in this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a variation of the idea I gave [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174472/45431):

```
Normal @ Series[
    ss /. {f:u1|u2 -> (s f[#1,#2,#3,#4]&)},
    {s, 0, 3}
] /. s->1
```

> u2[x, y, z, t]^3 + Derivative[0, 0, 0, 2][u1][x, y, z, t] + 
>    (3*λ*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][u1][x, y, z, t]^2*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][u1][x, y, z, t])/2 + 
>    μ*Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][u2][x, y, z, t]

Comment: working like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score -4):

```
Series[Sin[x + y + z], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 3}]
```